# Hoe to handle catch HTTP response in Angular?

Tags: angular

I use last version Angular and new package HttpClient to execute requests:

```
   return this.http.post('', data).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleErrorObservable())
    );
```

Where `handleErrorObservable` is my own function to handle exceptions:

```
private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
```

How to return Response to this method and handle exceptions?

Comment: It's not really clear of what you're trying to ask. You're already using the `catchError` operator. Whenever you `subscribe` whatever is returned from the above `this.http.post` code, you'll get this error over there. You can do the needful once you get ahold of the error.

Comment: First, it should be `private handleErrorObservable(error: HttpErrorResponse) {}` That what I wanted

Comment: Second instead `.catch` used something another in new version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first fix your `catchError`, as it applies `function` and returns `Observable`

```
return this.http.post('', data).pipe(
  catchError(error => this.handleErrorObservable(error))
);
```

in new version of `rxjs` there isn't `throw` operator in `Observable`, instead you should use `throwError`

```
import {throwError} from 'rxjs';

private handleErrorObservable(error: Response | any) {
    return throwError(error.message || error);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, but how return body and header in response ? not body result?

Comment: sorry I do not get your question, what you mean saying header and body?

Comment: I mean how to get from here headers and body: `return this.http.post('', data);`

Comment: I tried this: `return this.http.post('', data).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<Response>) =>{ 
          return response} ) 
    ); `

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.

```
return this.http.post('', data).pipe(
  catchError(err => this.handleErrorObservable(err))
);
```

Notice the `err` parameter, which is the error response you're looking for. Then I just pass it on.

Comment: Thank you, but how return body and header in response ? not body result?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. The error response has the structure described here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse